# Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^{1/4}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Solve
>   $$
> \int\frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^{1/4}}
> $$

Set $t=\log x\implies x=e^t\implies dt=\dfrac{dx}{x}$
$$
\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^{1/4}}=\int\frac{\dfrac{1}{x}dx}{\big(\dfrac{1}{x^4}+1\big)^{1/4}}=\int\frac{dt}{(e^{-4t}+1)^{1/4}}
$$
Set $e^{-4t}+1=y\implies-4e^{-4t}dt=dy$
$$
I=\int\frac{e^{-4t}\,dt}{e^{-4t}(e^{-4t}+1)^{1/4}} = \frac{-1}{4}\int\frac{dy}{(y-1) y^{1/4}}
$$

The solution given in my reference is $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\log\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}-\tan^{-1}z\right),\quad z=\frac{(1+x^4)^{1/4}}{x}$$

How do I see what substitution to choose in order to find such a solution ?

Comment: @PeterForeman truth is I did not see any helpful substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have 
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{(x-1)x^{1/4}},$$
take $x=u^4$ so that $dx=4u^3du$. We have $$I=4\int\frac{u^2du}{u^4-1}.$$
This is 
$$\begin{align}
\tfrac14I&=\int\frac{u^2du}{(u^2+1)(u^2-1)}\\
&=\frac12\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}+\frac14\int\frac{du}{u-1}-\frac14\int\frac{du}{u+1}.
\end{align}$$
The rest is easy from there.

Comment: This is an other integral!

Comment: @S.Maths note the portion of the question in which the OP reduces the problem to evaluating the integral $\int\frac{dy}{(y-1)y^{1/4}}$. This answer evaluates that integral